# can I execute shell command from jmx-console?

Tags: jboss, jmx

Purpose : I need to get ulimit value

Is there any way I can issue a shell command from jmx-console to extract java/jboss process's ulimit value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a standard setup. You would need a custom MBean, but I would not expose a simple shell call. Risky. You might look at some different libraries that expose limits like SIGAR.